# create archive in memory c++

Tags: c++, zlib, minizip

I create an archive in memory and for the test I write it to disk to check if it is not corrupted, it opens without errors, and you can see the size of file.txt corresponds to the real one, but when I open file.txt error that the archive is corrupted although the data is written, can you help me?

```
#include <minizip/unzip.h>
#include <minizip/zip.h>

// Callbacks for minizip to work with memory
voidpf open_memory(voidpf opaque, const char* filename, int mode) {
    return opaque;
}

uLong write_memory(voidpf opaque, voidpf stream, const void* buf, uLong size) {
    auto memory = static_cast<std::vector<char>*>(opaque);
    const char* start = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(buf);
    memory->insert(memory->end(), start, start + size);
    return size;
}

long tell_memory(voidpf opaque, voidpf stream) {
    auto memory = static_cast<std::vector<char>*>(opaque);
    return memory->size();
}

long seek_memory(voidpf opaque, voidpf stream, uLong offset, int origin) {
    return 0; // We don't really need this for our example
}

int close_memory(voidpf opaque, voidpf stream) {
    return 0;
}

int testerror_memory(voidpf opaque, voidpf stream) {
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    const char* myData = "This is data for my custom file.";
    uLong myDataLength = strlen(myData);

    std::vector<char> memoryBuffer;

    // Set up the minizip functions to write to our memory buffer
    zlib_filefunc_def funcs;
    funcs.zopen_file = open_memory;
    funcs.zwrite_file = write_memory;
    funcs.ztell_file = tell_memory;
    funcs.zseek_file = seek_memory;
    funcs.zclose_file = close_memory;
    funcs.zerror_file = testerror_memory;
    funcs.opaque = &memoryBuffer;

    zipFile zip = zipOpen2(nullptr, APPEND_STATUS_CREATE, nullptr, &funcs);
    if (zip) {
        zip_fileinfo zipfi = { 0 };

        zipOpenNewFileInZip(zip, "file.txt", &zipfi, nullptr, 0, nullptr, 0, nullptr, Z_DEFLATED, Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION);
        zipWriteInFileInZip(zip, myData, myDataLength);
        zipCloseFileInZip(zip);
        zipClose(zip, nullptr);

        std::cout << "ZIP archive has been created in memory." << std::endl;
    }
    std::ofstream out("memoryArchive.zip", std::ios::binary);
    if (out) {
        out.write(memoryBuffer.data(), memoryBuffer.size());
        out.close();
        std::cout << "ZIP archive has been saved to disk." << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "Failed to save the ZIP archive to disk." << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I could only get to the stage that the archive is opened without error, and the data is written, but apparently there is a break somewhere and incorrectly written.

Comment: `std::vector<char>*>` looks supspicious do you really need pointer sized memory allocations? Also char can be signed or unsigned depending on the platform you are on. Use `std::vector<std::uint8_t>`. For sizes of things do not use int or long but `std::size_t`

Answer (score 0):

Your `*_memory` functions look all wrong. First off, inserting into a vector is *not* the same as writing to a file. When you write to some position in a file, you are *overwriting* what's there. Not pushing the existing data up in the file.

I don't know why you think you don't need `seek`. Your `tell` operation should tell you where the current file pointer is, not the size of the file.

There may be other problems, but those were the first to jump out at me.